# pandas not saving content of table into csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have done something like this to create an empty dataframe and filling it. However, it looks like the output is empty, that is, only the header is created, not the rest of the data.

```
def create_data(self):
    mydf = pd.DataFrame(columns=<some header>)
    data = []
    for i in xrange(0, 10):
        data = something
        mydf.append(data)
    return mydf 

def print(self):
    data = self.create_data()
    data.to_csv(some_filename, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append) as it returns the result of the append:

```
def create_data(self):
    mydf = pd.DataFrame(columns=<some header>)
    data = []
    for i in xrange(0, 10):
        data = something
        mydf = mydf.append(data)
    return mydf
```

Comment: I thought it'd behave like Python lists

Comment: Never assume anything the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append state what the behaviour is

Comment: it is printing data in a single column.... do you know how to print it as a table?

Comment: define table and really this should be a new question